# Adding a new column based on random values in other column for multiple files simultaneously in R

Tags: r, dataframe

There are so many post regarding the same issue. But I could not find solution for this.  I have 140 individual files. Each files has the same columns as follows.

```
    taxy      taxx     
1  Alistipes  Roseburia         
2  Alistipes  Clostridium     
3  Alistipes  Clostridium
4  Dorea       Alistipes 
5 Clostridium  Alistipes 
6  Roseburia   Dora
```

I need to create two new columns (otuno) based on taxy and taxx respectively. For example,In taxy, more than 70 values are there. It is impossible to assign numbers for each values separately. My desire output looks like

```
taxy      taxx            taxyid   taxxid 
1  Alistipes  Roseburia     1   2
2  Alistipes  Clostridium   1   3
3  Dorea       Alistipes    4   1
4 Clostridium  Alistipes    3   1
5  Roseburia   Dorea        2   4
```

How do I perform this for 140 files together? All the files are in csv format

Comment: So you need unique number for each file which should be common for filenames in both the columns? So  if "Alistipes" is 4 in `taxyid`, it should also be 4 in `taxxid`?

Comment: @RonakShah Yeah exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `unlist` and gather all the `unique` values from the dataframe and add factor levels for each column based on that and convert it into integer.

```
unique_levels <- unique(unlist(df))

df[paste0(names(df), "_id")] <- lapply(df, function(x) 
                                as.integer(factor(x, levels = unique_levels)))
df

#         taxy        taxx taxy_id taxx_id
#1   Alistipes   Roseburia       1       4
#2   Alistipes Clostridium       1       3
#3   Alistipes Clostridium       1       3
#4       Dorea   Alistipes       2       1
#5 Clostridium   Alistipes       3       1
#6   Roseburia       Dorea       4       2
```

---

In `dplyr`, we can use `mutate_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_all(list(id = ~as.integer(factor(., levels = unique_levels))))
```

---

To apply this to multiple files, we can put the above code in a function

```
all_files <- list.files("path/of/files", full.names = TRUE)
cols <- c("taxx", "taxy")

apply_fun <- function(df) {
  unique_levels <- unique(unlist(df))
  df[paste0(cols, "_id")] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) as.integer(factor(x, levels = unique_levels)))
  return(df)
}
```

and apply the function to each file through `lapply` by reading the files using `read.csv` or any other method that you used.

```
lapply(seq_along(all_files), function(x) 
  write.csv(apply_fun(read.csv(all_files[x])), basename(all_files[x]), row.names = FALSE))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(taxy = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), 
.Label = c("Alistipes", "Clostridium", "Dorea", "Roseburia"), class = "factor"), 
taxx = structure(c(4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Alistipes", "Clostridium", 
"Dorea", "Roseburia"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: How do I do it for 140 files simultaneously. Should i use for loops?

Comment: @MSM by 140 files do you mean you have 140 columns?

Comment: no. 140 files. Each file has two columns taxx and taxy.

Comment: Can you check the update answer? This will give you list of new updated dataframes in `new_files`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the output. But I insert fwrite(df,  file = ".csv") in the fucntion to save those into separate files. no files have saved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206334/discussion-between-msm-and-ronak-shah).